# Сделать скрипт, после обновлении страницы нажатие по кнопке на сайте

Tags: jquery, tampermonkey

Кнопка появляется после обновления страницы:
[image: Кнопка]
Код кнопки на страницы:
[image: Код]
Примерный код для Tampermonkey (не работает):
[image: Скрипт(пример)]

Comment: пожалуйста, вместо картинок - укажите код  текстом.

Comment: у вас синтаксическая ошибка здесь - остутствует `{ `  в 13 строке

Answer (score 0):

У вас в коде:

1. синтаксическая ошибка - строка 14
2. неверная ссылка на document - `$("document")`
3. неверно указан селектор для элемента для поиска элемента для click'a

Попробуйте так:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".mm-queue-actions .btn-primary").click();
    });
}) ();
```

**Обновлено**

Для того, чтобы "поджигать" событие click у кнопки, сразу после ее появления на странице - добавляем обработчик события `DOMSubtreeModified`:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    $(document)
    .bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
      $(".mm-queue-actions .btn-primary").click();
     })
    .ready(function () {
        $(".mm-queue-actions .btn-primary").click();
    });
}) ();
```

Comment: к сожалению не работает.

Comment: @антонЛеонов Обновил ответ

Comment: Работает, но у меня обмена нету но он открывается, можно как то сделать что бы открывался только тогда когда есть обмен ?

Comment: @антонЛеонов Сложно ответить - мало информации. Что такое "есть обмен"? Скорее всего нужно привязаться к событию DOM страницы.

Comment: на сайте я покупаю карточки, и всплывает сверху иконка обмена и надо на ее нажимать. Могу скинуть по шагам как работает, но куда скидывать я не знаю.

Comment: @антонЛеонов, т.е. нажимать нужно кнопку сразу, как она появится на странице в окошке  "Your trade is ready!"?

Comment: да, все верно. правильно

Comment: @антонЛеонов обновил ответ

Comment: все работает, но все равно открывается когда обмена нету и когда он появляется он открывается и открывается постоянно.

Comment: Мало информации о коде страницы, чтобы правильно написать обработчик (

Comment: скажите чего код нужен ?, я вам предоставлю.

Comment: В идеале, мне "нужна" живая страница, чтобы подобрать способ обработки события

Comment: https://scrap.tf/buy/weapons, только нужно что то купить что бы обмен вышел.